# How do I use acts-as-taggable-on in a test fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, fixtures, acts-as-taggable-on

It looks like acts-as-taggable-on uses polymorphic relations in the data tables it sets up.  How do I get this to work with fixtures in minitest?

I have a `Lead` model that implements `acts-as-taggable`.  It looks like this adds the following into the model:

```
has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging"
has_many :base_tags, :through => :taggings, :source => :tag, :class_name => "ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag"
```

My Leads table:

```
  create_table "leads", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Tables created by acts-as-taggable-on:

```
  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

There's a Tagging class in the gem that includes:

```
belongs_to :tag, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'
belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :tagger,   :polymorphic => true
```

And here are what my fixtures look like following the [rails api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Polymorphic+belongs_to) for polymorphic relationships:

```
# leads.yml
onetag1:
  name: "OneTag1 Lead"
  email: "lead@onetag1email.com"
  phone: "14120006002"
  base_tags: one
onetag2:
  name: "OneTag2 Lead"
  email: "lead@onetag2email.com"
  phone: "14120006003"

# taggings.yml
one:
  tag: one
  taggable: onetag1 (Lead)
two:
  tag: two
  taggable: onetag2 (Lead)

# tags.yml
one:
  name: "Tag one"
two:
  name: "Tag two"
```

But I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "tag" of relation "taggings" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag", "taggable") VALUES ('one', 'o...
                                ^
: INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag", "taggable") VALUES ('one', 'onetag1 (Lead)')
```

I also tried just:

```
# taggings.yml
one:
  taggable: onetag1 (Lead)
two:
  taggable: onetag2 (Lead)
```

without the reference to `tag`.  But here I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggable" of relation "taggings" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "taggings" ("taggable") VALUES ('onetag1 (Lead)'...
                                ^
: INSERT INTO "taggings" ("taggable") VALUES ('onetag1 (Lead)')
```

What am I missing?  And how do I associate tags with my leads in the fixture?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is reordering the fixtures so tags are before taggings.  In your fixture the tags don't exist yet when you try to assign them.  I could be wrong as I don't work with fixtures.

Comment: Joe, they're in separate files.

Comment: I think you might need something like `tag_id: one.id` and `taggable_id: onetag1.id`.  It seems like the fixtures create raw queries rather than relying on the model association definitions.  My evidence is in the error: `column tag does not exist` and `column taggings does not exist`

Comment: According to the api, I shouldn't need to.  Polymorphic relationships should be able to be specified in the format:
child:
  polymorphic_name: parent_object_name (Parent_class)

...according to the api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Polymorphic+belongs_to

Comment: I agree the API states that, but this behavior is betraying that fact.  Regarding the tag attribute, I would recommend trying `tag_id: tag.id` because that association is not like the one described in the polymorphic section of the docs.  It's just a plain belongs to relationship.  An alternative to this approach is to do tag assignment within your test suite.  I would also caution against testing the behavior of an API if that's what you're after here.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  When you say "caution against testing the behavior of an API", are you saying to not do the tag assignment within the test suite?  Or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106632/discussion-between-joe-essey-and-stephen-horvath).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but for anyone who happens upon this through a search, here's the solution (at least in Rails 5).

The key is in Rails' magic around folders and class names.  Because acts-as-taggable-on creates modules under the ActsAsTaggableOn namespace, the fixtures need to be created in a subfolder called `acts_as_taggable_on`

### Fixture Data

Under the fixtures folder, the tagging related fixtures should be in the paths indicated here:

```
# acts_as_taggable_on/taggings.yml
one:
  tag: one
  taggable: onetag1 (Lead)
two:
  tag: two
  taggable: onetag2 (Lead)

# acts_as_taggable_on/tags.yml
one:
  name: "Tag one"
two:
  name: "Tag two"
```

### Fixtures in Test Cases

To retrieve tags or taggings in test cases, use the following:

```
setup do
  @tag = acts_as_taggable_on_tags(:one)
  @tagging = acts_as_taggabe_on_taggings(:one)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ryan answer is mostly correct, but you might also need to specify the context on your taggings fixture like this.

```yaml
# acts_as_taggable_on/taggings.yml
one:
  tag: one
  taggable: onetag1 (Lead)
  context: tags
two:
  tag: two
  taggable: onetag2 (Lead)
  context: tags
```

The tags fixture also has a counter cache

```yaml
# acts_as_taggable_on/tags.yml
one: 
  name: tag one
  taggings_count: 1
```